# three.js abrupt viewport clipping

Tags: webgl, three.js

I'm using Three.js to draw some tetrahedrons using the WebGL renderer and an OrthographicCamera. `THREE.OrthographicCamera(-ww, ww, hh, -hh, -100000, 100000);` They are generated like this:

```
var ret = new THREE.Mesh();
var retGeom = new THREE.Geometry();
var side = Math.sqrt(3);
var th = (Math.sqrt(6)/3)*side;
var rad = side*(Math.sqrt(3)/3);
var inrad = side*(Math.sqrt(3)/6);
var ang = Math.PI*2/3;

retGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,th));
retGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.cos(0)*rad,Math.sin(0)*rad,0));
retGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.cos(ang)*rad,Math.sin(ang)*rad,0));
retGeom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(Math.cos(-ang)*rad,Math.sin(-ang)*rad,0));

retGeom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 2, 0, null, new THREE.Color(0xff00ff), 0));
retGeom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 0, 2, null, new THREE.Color(0x0000ff), 0));
retGeom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 1, 0, null, new THREE.Color(0xffff00), 0));
retGeom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 2, 1, null, new THREE.Color(0x00ff00), 0));
```

I use multiplyScalar(...) on the verts to set the size.
The material used is `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors})`. 
The most basic onResize I've tried is like this:

```
ww = window.innerWidth;
hh = window.innerHeight;

renderer.setSize(ww, hh);
camera.aspect = ww/hh;
camera.left = -ww;
camera.right = ww;
camera.top = hh;
camera.bottom = -hh;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

Anyway, the problem I'm having happens when the center point of the tetrahedron leaves the side of the window because of resizing or panning with the built in trackball controls. Even though this would leave part of it still on screen and in the window, the whole thing stops rendering at this point.

I've tried different cameras and have seen similar behavior. I also thought it might be fixable with setViewport(...) or setScissor(...), which I played with a little with no success.

Does anyone know hot to get the objects to render until they are completely off screen? I'm fairly inexperienced in this area and feel like there might be a simple solution here that I'm missing.

Comment: Does the problem occur with PerspectiveCamera? Also, have a look at this thread: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/448 (It's old, so the jsfiddles don't work.) Perhaps this is a bug with OrthographicCamera only. Can you create a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The issue you referenced lead me to try calling `updateBoundingSphere()` on my geometry after doing my scale and everything seems to behave as expected now. Thanks a lot!